# How to remove first line from a String containing XML?

Tags: java

I have a string which contains XML.
I want to remove its first line and save it back to String.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming there's a new line at the end of the string that you would like to remove, you can do this:

```
s = s.substring(s.indexOf('\n')+1);
```

When there are no new lines, `s` would remain the same.

Answer (score 8):

Technically, because Macs (up to OS 9) used to use `\r` and as the accepted solution doesn't solve this, it would make sense to use:

```
s = s.substring(s.indexOf(System.getProperty("line.separator"))+1);
```

But as it was mentioned in the comments, when using this code you have to make sure you don't work e.g. on source code files with `Unix` line endings on `Windows`.

Comment: Since the only two line separation schemes that are common are `\n` and `\r\n`, and the literal `\n` works for both, I think it's more reliable than `line.separator`.  Consider, for example, that when working with source code files with unix line endings on Windows, this approach will fail, while the above will succeed. So looking for `\r\n` on Windows is more likely to create a platform-specific bug than to prevent one, in this case.